# Bigcommerce create product PHP

Tags: php, sql, api, bigcommerce

This is a Bigcommerce PHP API question.

I have an array:

```
$fields = array(
  "name" => $row[1],
  "price" => $row[5],
  "category" => $row[14],
  "weight" => $row[8],
  "sku" => $row[2],
  'type' => 'physical',
  'availability' => 'available',
  'is_visible' => true
);
```

And I have a function:

```
  function create_product($fields) {
    try {
      echo "Attempting to create product";
      echo "\r\n";
      Bigcommerce::createProduct($fields);
    } catch(Bigcommerce\Api\Error $error) {
      echo $error->getCode();
      echo $error->getMessage();
    }
  }
```

I am getting no error and the product is not showing up on our Bigcommerce store. Any ideas?

I have verified:
1) I can connect to the store
2) I can retrieve time from the store

Comment: I may have found the problem. Is it 'category' or 'categories'? And is it by category name (string) or by category id?

Answer (score 0):

Directy from the [bigcommerce api documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products)

> The following properties of the product are required. The request
>   won’t be fulfilled unless these properties are valid.
>
> name price categories type availability weight

Comment: see my edits. I've added those fields and still receive no error and no listed product

Comment: I'm sure it said something about "skus" (typo?) being a read-only value and should not be included in the request, can you try remove it?

Comment: I removed that and did not make an impact. I wish I could see the error message so I could further diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is 'categories' and it needs type array with id of category.

Thanks!